# Python multithreading event listener

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, queue, esp32

unfortunately, I can't put any sample code here (work reasons), but maybe I can describe the problem well enough in words to be understood. Also, sorry for my English in advance.

I want to have 4 ESP32 devices connected to a Raspberry Pi, which will send continuously streamed data from the ESPs to AWS IoT Core. My idea was to open 4 threads (one for each ESP) and listen to the serial ports (this part works already quite well). Then the data will be `put()` in a queue where the MQTT client (running in another thread) will listen to the queue and `get()` the messages to be sent by the client. Now this concept will create at least two forever loops (one for each thread listening to the ports and one for the MQTT client). I know that a **"while True:"** loop isn't an optimal solution in terms of occupancy of the core.
Is there some kind of way to replace it with a type of event listener, that will be called, once a message from the ports and in the queue is available?

Thanks a lot guys and happy coding

Comment: Use one thread per serial connection. BTW is there any reason you don't let the ESP32s connect to the broker directly?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. I have a function that reads out all the serial connections automatically and creates a thread for each connected serial port. We want to use the data, later on, to run near real-time calculations on the PI and respond to the ESP on site. So the IoT Core with S3 will be only there for storing short event messages.

Comment: You can use local MQTT broker on Pi to get the data from ESP.

Comment: We have a physical serial connection, so a serial read for the ESPs on the PI is sufficient.